# Present UINavigationController from anywhere in view hierarchy?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

You'll note that a ton of people have written articles describing their difficulty with navigation controllers, and getting that message about "tried to present XYZ on ABC whose view is not in the view hierarchy"

Well, I'm having a ton of similar issues, and I suspect that it has something to do with trying to present a navigation controller from any ol' arbitrary view controller in a view hierarchy, which is precisely what I'm trying to do.

As best I can tell, every example I've found that demonstrates using a UINavigationController, uses it as the ROOT VIEW CONTROLLER just below window, and the frustrating part about that is no one makes it clear whether THAT is in fact the only way you can use a UINavigationController, or whether you can use it from any depth you want in the hierarchy and have it work fine.

In any case, I'm getting the dreaded "view not in hierarchy" message as well, and just want to know, is it true that a UINavigationController MUST always and only be used from the root of the entire view hierarchy.

If that's not true, how can I properly use it from any arbitrary depth in my hierarchy, because clearly I'm not doing it right, lol.

Comment: That's not true. You can use a navigation controller anywhere. It likely has something to do with what you're attempting to present it over.

Comment: Where is your presentViewController code located? (e.g. viewDidLoad, etc.)

Comment: @AdamPro13 -  I'm presenting it from a less-than-full-screen sized view, and triggering its creation/presentation when the user does a double-tap gesture on said view.

Comment: @beyowulf  - It's in a double-tap gesture handler for a less-than-full-screen view.

Comment: Try presenting it from a full screen sized view controller.

Comment: @AdamPro13  Yes I'm painfully trying to rework some code to do that.  I'm multiple levels deep in the hierarchy from any full screen view. :(

Comment: One thing I did to help me situations like this is a created a static method that returns the app's root view controller. For example, I call `[RootViewController sharedRootViewController` which will return `[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController`. It's a bit of a hack, but it works.

Comment: @AdamPro13  At this point I'm ready to try just about anything.  Getting ready to leave for the day, but will try it tonight or tomorrow.

Comment: @LogicsaurusRex Since a nav controller can be shown from just about anywhere, you should delete this question and post a new one that address the actual problem you are having trying to present the nav controller and getting the error. Show relevant code detailing how you try to show the nav controller. Include sufficient context. Also show code detailing how the view controller trying to present the nav controller was itself displayed on screen.

Comment: @rmaddy  Hopefully we can close the question, rather than delete it.  I've deleted several questions already and am at risk of having my account disabled from asking questions.  I've already posted several questions on this particular issue, from different angles that might discover the problem.  I'm going to make a skeleton app this weekend that hopefully will help me discover the problem, or at least illustrate it to others.